# Edit GRUB menu with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, android

I installed some kind of multiboot device to be able to use Android on my laptop.

I would like to change the boot order to make Windows the default option,
but I need to do it from within Windows 10, as I don't have Ubuntu installed. My laptop is old and still uses BIOS.

Boot menu:

[image: boot menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can install Grub2Win (https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) in your Windows and edit the Grub menu. Please remember: if you choose to uninstall GRUB bootloader, you will need to repair the Windows bootloader.

Comment: Downloading this crap modified my default grub and installed an awful one. This is NOT a Grub editor, more of a Grub replacement, that will install without asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set some entry in the GRUB as default, you should edit `/etc/default/grub` with your favourite text editor on Linux (Android is based on it, so you should find some Terminal Emulator for console-based stuff).

The thing you should edit is `GRUB_DEFAULT` value.
`0` means choosing the first value in the menu entry if no input will be given.
Try changing it to `saved` or just `2`.

`saved` will always choose your last choice, 2 sets your third option (counting from 0) in the menu.

After applying changes you should recreate your boot entries by `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: For `saved`, don't you also need to add the line `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`?  Regardless, the `saved` feature doesn't work for me and I have to manually choose every single time, or hard code it to an integer.  :-(   Pretty sad how broken this super basic software is in the year 2021...